# Setting a menu to close after X amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(showmenu) {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle().delay('1000');
    });
});
```

Where and how would I set a time out to close the menu (which drops down upon click) so that after X amount of time, the menu is hidden again.

Comment: Go vanilla: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(showmenu) {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle().delay('1000');
            setTimeout(function(){$('.menu').hide()}, 5000);
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IAmko